# JS: Check string if it is failing for some rules

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

**Issue**

Using regex to verify if a string is matching specific rules.

**My Problem**

My regexes seems not to bee valid and I don't know how to check a string for multiple regexes.

**Example string**

```
This is just a senseless  string with less then 1.000,00 words. and 1 x abbrevations e.g. this one ( and so on).
```

**Rules**

```
Every sentence must begin with an upper case character or a number
There must not be a space between number and `x`
Never multiple spaces
There must not be spaces at the beginning and at the end of bracket content
```

**My regex attempts**

```
/([.?!])\s*(?= [A-Z0-9])/g          // Sentence have to start with upper case
/([0-9]*)(x)/g                      // No space between number and 'x'
/\s{2,}/g                           // Two or more spaces
// don't know how to do last rule

if (/([.?!])\s*(?= [A-Z0-9])/.test(string); )
    failing.push('capitalizeSentence');
else if ...
```

But maybe it can by done a bit more dynamic...

**Expected result**

I need to know which rules are not matching the string if there is any. So I would suggest an array with values for those rules failed.
So in this example string the result could be an array like this, as every rule is failing.

```
failing = [ 'capitalizeSentence', 'spaceNumber', 'multipleSpaces', 'spaceBrackets' ];
```

Comment: Some of those rules are easier to check for when they're broken rather than when they're not. For example, your second rule would be easier as `/\d\s+x/`. If there's a match, the string failed that rule.

Comment: @Ouroborus That's a very good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
var rules = {
  'capitalizeSentence': /[.?!]\s+[^A-Z\d]/,
  'spaceNumber': /\d\s+x/,
  'multipleSpaces': /\s\s/,
  'spaceBrackets': /\(\s|\s\)/
}
var check = function(str){
  return Object.keys(rules).reduce(function(results,key){
    if(rules[key].test(str)) {
      results.push(key);
    }
    return results;
  },[]);
};
console.log(check('This is just a senseless  string with less then 1.000,00 words. and 1 x abbrevations e.g. this one ( and so on).'));
```

Operates by checking for rules violations and adding those violation names to an array which is returned.

Comment: Just for deeper understanding: How would I use `/\(\s|\s\)/` in a `replace()` to remove those spaces?

Comment: @user3142695 Easiest would be to split it into two tests. More difficult would be to rearrange the regex so you could take advantage of capturing groups.

Comment: I would think something like `.replace(/\(\s(.*)\s\)/, '($1)');`

Comment: @user3142695 Assuming the parenthesis are always matched and there are spaces on both ends, yes.

Comment: `.replace(/(\()(?:\s+)|(?:\s+)(\))/g,"$1$2")`